# Importing data from oracle using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

i am using below command to import table into hadoop from oracle using sqoop. but i m getting errors. As i am noob in hadoop i have no idea how to fix it.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.10.112:1523:TABS" --username testuser1 --password testuser1 --table tabs.user_info --target-dir /tmp –verbose


Generic Hadoop command-line arguments:
(must preceed any tool-specific arguments)
Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>    specify a ResourceManager
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]


At minimum, you must specify --connect and --table
Arguments to mysqldump and other subprograms may be supplied
after a '--' on the command line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dash (-) in verbose is different

Comment: yes.. the sqoop specific commands should have (`--`) before it.

Comment: thanks. i am so silly that i didnot add -- before verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify database in the table selection. Because the database `TABS` is already selected in connection string,

replace,

```
--table tabs.user_info
```

with

```
--table user_info
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: tabs is schema name. which is main schema of TABS database. now i have changed as per your suggestion but got same error.

Comment: it is not error, it means you are missing/special characters in the sqoop parameters. Try out some basic sqoop script like `list-table` or `eval` and check if you are getting error still.